# Check if array empty in php

Tags: php, arrays

No doubt it has been discussed few million times here and yes once again I am posting something related with it.

I have the following code.

```
$address = "#&#&#&";
$addr = explode("#&",$address);
```

it returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

Now the values are empty.So I am doing a check.

```
If(!empty($addr))
{
echo 'If print then something wrong';
}
```

And it still prints that line.Not frustrated yet but will be soon

Comment: [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#refsect1-function.preg-split-parameters) flag may be of interest to you. It splits strings based on a regular expression and allows you to discard empty pieces with the mentioned option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove empty entries, then check if the array itself is empty()

```
if (empty(array_filter($addr)))
```

Note that array_filter() without a callback will remove any "falsey" entries, including 0

Answer (score 2):

To check if the array contains no values you could loop the array and unset the no values and then check if the array is empty like the following.

```
$addresses = "#&#&#&";
$addresses = explode("#&", $addresses);

foreach ( $addresses as $key => $val ) {
   if ( empty($val) ) {
      unset($addresses[$key]);
   }
}

if ( empty($addresses) ) {
   echo 'there are no addresses';
}
else {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake.I will prefer to check before going down through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an empty array, empty array has no elements, your have four elements, each being an empty string, this is why `empty` is returning `false`.

You have to iterate over elements and test whether they are all empty, like

```
$empty=True;
foreach ($addr as $el){ 
 if ($el){
  $empty=False;
  break;
 }
}

if (!$empty) echo "Has values"; else echo "Empty";
```

Comment: Wouldn't work. Since you're not checking if it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the array contains elements in it. What you want to do is check if the elements in the array are empty strings.

```
foreach ($addr as $item) {
    if (empty($item)) {
        echo 'Empty string.';
    } else {
        echo 'Value is: '.item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is not empty, it has 4 items. Here's a possible solution:

```
$hasValues = false;

foreach($addr as $v){
    if($v){
        $hasValues = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$hasValues){
    echo 'no values';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside of the box, your task appears to want to validate that no values have been added beyond the delimiting character sequences.  For this reason, you don't actually need to produce an array, then check that array.  Instead, just check if the input string is fully comprised of your delimiting sequences.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bA1QX))

```
$address = "#&#&#&";
$delimiter = '#&';
if (preg_match('~^(?:' . preg_quote($delimiter) . ')+$~', $address)) {
    echo 'Text comprised solely of one or more delimiting substrings';
}
```

In truth the `preg_quote()` call is not actually needed, I just thought it would make the answer more robust for general use.  The pattern can simply be `/^(?:#&)+$/`.