# How to see if an array of associative arrays is empty in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, is-empty

I have a fairly easy issue where I need to see if an associative array of arrays is empty in php. My array looks like this:

```
array (
  'person1' => 
  array (
  ),
  'person2' => 
  array (
  ),
  'person3' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

In my case, the three array's for the three people holds nothing so I need a test whether this is empty. I have done this which works:

```
    if ( empty($form_values['person1']) && empty($form_values['person2']) && empty($form_values['person3'] ) ){
        echo 'values empty!!';
    }
```

But I was hoping something a bit more cleaner with using empty like the following:

```
if (empty( $form_values )) {
  echo 'HI!';
}
```

Comment: How is your array generated? It would be best to just not include the empty subarrays in the first place, then you could just check if `$form_values` is empty as you do. My only other suggestion would be to use a loop. `foreach($array as $a) { if(empty($a)) die() }`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Your loop dies if any of the values are empty, not if all of them are.

Comment: @Barmar Ah you're right

Comment: There is a significant volume of answers from [Check if array empty in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25100240/2943403) which will provide the desired outcome despite the sample input of that question being a flat array.  And here is a recursive page for more dynamic array structures: [How to check if all values in multidimensional array are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19992280/2943403).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a one-liner then you could do something like:

```
$form_values = array (
  'person1' => 
  array (
  ),
  'person2' => 
  array (
  ),
  'person3' => 
  array (
  ),
);

if(array_sum(array_map(function($v){return !empty($v);}, $form_values)) === 0)
{
    // empty
}
else
{
    // not empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter()` to filter all of the empty array elements. You can then use `empty` to check if the result is empty then.

I've shorthanded the arrays so it's a easier to read since the arrays are empty. `array()` will work the same.

```php
$form_values = [
  'person1' => [],
  'person2' => [],
  'person3' => []
];

if (empty(array_filter($form_values))) {
    // empty
} else {
    // not empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop that tests each nested array. If none of them are non-empty, the whole array is empty.

```
$is_empty = true;
foreach ($form_values as $val) {
    if (!empty($val)) {
        $is_empty = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That should work as well as the other answer.

Comment: @raven This is currently the only answer on the page that is executing the best practice of short circuiting as soon as a false outcome is encountered.  For this reason, this will be the best performer of the lot.

Comment: @mickmackusa It's unfortunate that PHP doesn't have functions like JavaScript's `Array.prototype.every/some()` or Python's `all/any()`. So all the array composition methods must traverse the entire array.

Comment: There are two reasons why I haven't yet upped this answer. 1. `empty()` is an unneeded function call to make a falsey check on a variable guaranteed to be declared and 2. I haven't checked thoroughly for dupe targets.

Comment: 1. "Explicit is better than implicit". I particularly like to be explicit in example code.

Comment: `empty()` performs the same behaviour as `key_exists($val) === false || $val == false`.  However, the variable is unconditionally declared, so the `key_exists()` check is unnecessary work.  If you prefer to use a word instead of `!$val`, then `count($val) === 0` is explicit.  In this context it would also be explicit to use `$val === []`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = 
[
    'pig' => [],
    'hog' => [],
    'sow' => []
];

$all_empty = array_filter($data) === [];
var_dump($all_empty);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

From the manual for array_filter:

> If no callback is supplied, all empty entries of array will be
> removed. See empty() for how PHP defines empty in this case.

Note that if an item was deemed as empty, like an empty string, it would still return true.  This test may not be strict enough.

More explicitly:

```
if (array_filter($data, function($v) {return $v !== []; }) === []) {}
```

Filter out all items that aren't the empty array.  What we'll be left with is an empty array if all items are an empty array.

Or search and compare:

```
if (array_keys($data, []) == array_keys($data)) {}
```

Check keys belonging to items containing the empty array match the keys of the array.  Or rather all items (if they exist) are the empty array.

Note that an empty array will also satisfy the three solutions above.